# Password hashing for php 5.3.3

Tags: php, hash, php-5.3, password-protection

So I read alot of topics here on stackoverflow.
Most of them say that password_hash is the best, but Its only for php 5.5.5.

So what is the best hashing for php 5.3.3? And shall I hash it?

Thank you

Comment: Here is a [backwards compatible password_hash() for pre-5.5 versions of PHP](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: It needs to be for 5.3.3 and may not be "hashed -> plaintext" Only "plaintext -> hashed"

Comment: Password hash requires a minimum PHP >= 5.5.0 (not 5.5.5) and the userland version for backward compatibility requires PHP >= 5.3.7 but if you're still on PHP 5.3.3 you should really consider upgrading

Comment: Note that `"hashed -> plaintext"` is (by definition) not possible; you can't reconstitute a cow from a beefburger

Comment: Mark Baker I also said it may NOT be "hashed -> plaintext"

Comment: Even for lower PHP versions than 5.3.7 you can use the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php). You only have to edit line 55 and change the algorithm from `sprintf("$2y$%02d$", $cost);` to `sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost);`. This is of course not optimal, but it is the best you can do for PHP earlier than 5.3.7.